# Reshaping the third column of a CSV file into a matrix

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file and I'd like to reshape the first 3 columns into a matrix.
I have a data.frame that looks like this.

```
x a 1 
x b 2 
x c 3 
y a 3 
y b 3 
y c 2
```

I want this in matrix form so I can feed it to heatmap to make a plot. The result should look something like:

```
    a    b    c
x   1    2    3
y   3    3    2
```

I have tried cast from the reshape package and I have tried writing a manual function to do this but I do not seem to be able to get it right.

The CSV file is very large (900mB) and in the first column there's a lot of x,y,z's so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using `dcast` fucntion.

```
library(reshape2)
textData <- "x a 1 
x b 2 
x c 3 
y a 3 
y b 3 
y c 2 "

data <- read.table(textConnection(textData), header=FALSE)
dcast(data, V1 ~ V2, value.var="V3")
```

Comment: Specifying the data may be unpractical becuase there are too many observations in the csv file (900mB). Is there a way I can load the csv into R and convert it into a matrix?

Comment: You can create a matrix by using `library(reshape2)` and function `dcast` in it

    library(reshape2)
    
    dcast(dt,A~B)
    
     A a b c
    1 X 1 2 3
    2 Y 3 3 2

#data

    dt <- data.frame(A = c(rep("X",3),rep("Y",3)),B=c("a","b","c","a","b","c"), C= c(1,2,3,3,3,2))

Comment: Try `data.table` package. They also have an implementation of `dcast`, which is optimised and will take only the specified columns only. Alternatively you can read entire data, and delete the columns, which are not required in `dcast`.

Comment: Thanks. How would you export the table into a excel spreadsheet?

Comment: You can use `write.csv` function.