# How to reshape a column in csv file into matrix form using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need help in reshaping a column(Column 'Break') in csv file that looks like this

```
Axe Break
1   ww
2   ee
3   qq
4   xx
5   dd
5   gg
4   hh
6   tt
9   yy
1   uu
1   ii
2   oo
5   pp
4   mm
5   kk
5   ll
7   mm
2   bb
7   pp
0   zz
```

into a matrix form like this

```
[[ww,ee,qq,xx,dd,gg,hh,tt,yy,uu],
 [ii,oo,pp,mm,kk,ll,mm,bb,pp,zz]]
```

using pandas.

I found a question that looks like what I want to ask here but I think that question a little different from what I want to do.

[Reshaping the third column of a CSV file into a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623731/reshaping-the-third-column-of-a-csv-file-into-a-matrix)

I have been going through the pandas tutorial but did not seem to find a way to do this.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reshape.

```
In [702]: df['Break'].reshape(2, len(df.index)/2)
Out[702]:
array([['ww', 'ee', 'qq', 'xx', 'dd', 'gg', 'hh', 'tt', 'yy', 'uu'],
       ['ii', 'oo', 'pp', 'mm', 'kk', 'll', 'mm', 'bb', 'pp', 'zz']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It worked but I did some other modification to add another row. (In the question it is only 2 row). I want to add another row so it becomes 3 row. I changed `reshape(2, len(df.index)/2` to `reshape(3, len(df.index)/3) but it return an error saying `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged` . What exactly the number 2 means?

Comment: In `reshape(m, n)`, `m*n` equals number of elements. So, you need to pick the distribution accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I can manipulate the shape now.

Comment: @Fang `reshape(m, -1)` will ensure that the `m` is respected and the `-1` indicates that the other dimension will be what it needs to be.

Answer (score 3):

You can first create column for new `index` with `cumsum`, then [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and last convert to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
df['g'] = (df.Axe == 1).cumsum()
df = df.pivot(index='g', columns='Axe', values='Break')
       .reindex(columns=list(range(1,10)) + [0])

print (df)
Axe   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0
g                                          
1    ww  ee  qq  xx  dd  gg  hh  tt  yy  uu
2    ii  oo  pp  mm  kk  ll  mm  bb  pp  zz

print (df.values)
[['ww' 'ee' 'qq' 'xx' 'dd' 'gg' 'hh' 'tt' 'yy' 'uu']
 ['ii' 'oo' 'pp' 'mm' 'kk' 'll' 'mm' 'bb' 'pp' 'zz']]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It worked if there is no duplicate entries but what if there is duplicate entries?Column "Axe" has duplicate entries

Comment: Solution is similar only need change `df['g'] = (df.Axe == 1).cumsum()` to another code which return same values for each group.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `values` attribute drops this to `numpy` and then the `reshape` parameters can take `-1` in the dimension that needs to be determined.

```
df.Break.values.reshape(2, -1)

array([['ww', 'ee', 'qq', 'xx', 'dd', 'gg', 'hh', 'tt', 'yy', 'uu'],
       ['ii', 'oo', 'pp', 'mm', 'kk', 'll', 'mm', 'bb', 'pp', 'zz']], dtype=object)
```